# How to get postgres array's current index & not an value of index

Tags: arrays, postgresql

```
FOREACH v_name IN ARRAY name_list  
  
LOOP

 IF v_name = name_list[1]

    <perform some steps> 
    
 END IF;

END LOOP;
```

In my postgres function, I'm using the above expression in `if` condition, where `v_name` is an text variable and `name_list` is a `text[]` (array text variable).
with `name_list[1]`, It gives value of 1st indexed array, But I want to change this expression, and Verify it for the current index of array and not a value of array.
So if current index is 1 then perform some statements.

So my question is to how to get what is current index of array in postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the subscripts:

```
DECLARE
   i integer;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN array_lower(name_list, 1)..array_upper(name_list, 1) LOOP
      -- do something with "i" and "name_list[i]"
   END LOOP;
END;
```